# Processing custom XML namespace within XSL

Tags: php, xslt

I'm using the php class XSLTProcessor to generate HTML from a xsl. Within the xsl, I'd like all my custom namespace elements to be processed by my own processor class.

So for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc/elements/*">
    <doc:renderElement element="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

This should call the method renderElement of an instance of my custom processor class.

I know I can enable calling php functions by using the [registerPHPFunctions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) function. However, this only seems to support calling static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions` only supports static function calls of classes. However you can make use of those static calls to provide a *factory* or *instance registry* to provide actual objects. In your case probably based on the element name.

Existing code where this is done can be found in the [PIWI - PHP Transformation Framework](http://www.piwiframework.de/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. PIWI seems like a great resource for the project I'm working on. I'll dive into it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have a script using this, maybe it will be util for you

```
    // Simple XML
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
     // You need to set every namespace
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('e', 'http://myxml.withalotofnamespaces.com/xml');
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//e:responseData/e:cityCodes') as $city) {
       // getting each city as an Array,  $city is a SimpleXMLElement
       // Work Here
    }
```

If you want to try read in portuguese, here are a lot of other information for handle namespace XML using PHP with SimpleXMLFormt:
http://www.plugandpray.com.br/posts/manipulando_xml_com_namespace_em_php

About SimpleXMLFormat
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: This would be a great article when i want to process my custom elements before or after the document is transformed. However, my elements should be rendered during the xls transformation so I can use for-each etc.